# JS: Удалить все элементы массива кроме содержащих текст

Tags: javascript, массивы

Возьмем для примера какой то простой массив:

```
var array = ["Какой текст","Еще какой то текст и слово улица","И еще текст","И опять слово улица","И снова текст"];
```

Как на JavaScript'e удалить с такого массива все элементы кроме тех которые содержат слово "улица"?

Чтобы получилось

```
var array = ["Еще какой то текст и слово улица","И опять слово улица"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var array = [/** ваш массив */];
array = array.filter(function(val) { return val.indexOf("улица") + 1 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
var array = ["Какой текст","Еще какой то текст и слово улица","И ще текст","И опять слово улица","И снова текст"];

var tmpArr = [];
for (let i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i].match(/улица/i)) {
    tmpArr.push(array[i]);
  }
}

array = tmpArr;
console.log(array);
```

Comment: У меня работает если `for (var i=0;`